# How to implement elliptic filters in matlab that passes 8Hz to 35Hz?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I have a sampled signal represented as matrix which needs to be filtered to allow only 8-35 Hz. The result also should be a matrix !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'fdatool' to create your filter. Select the Response type `Bandpass` and the design methode `IIR - Elliptic`. Now you can fill in your freqency/magnitude specifications and Magnitude check the Magnitude/Phase response. When you are satisfied hit `File > Generate Matlab Code` and select `Data Filtering Function`.

Comment: Thank you :) lemme try this.. !!
I thought of using "ellip"

Comment: The GUI I recomended will most likely gernerate a filtering function which uses 'ellip' internally, you can see how to create the filter in commandline when you look at the generated comments in the functions m-file