# How to implement elliptic filter in matlab?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

[How to implement elliptic filters in matlab that passes 8Hz to 35Hz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421881/how-to-implement-elliptic-filters-in-matlab-that-passes-8hz-to-35hz?answertab=active#tab-top)

I tried it !! but i am not satisfied with the answer

I have a signal sampled at 100Hz represented as a matrix. I need to filter the signal to allow freq 8-35Hz.
The returned value also needs to be in a matrix representation !!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it is that you are not satisfied with? Also, what is your matrix representation (I'd assume columns or rows of signals to be treated independently)?

Comment: matrix is of the form 26455*118 where
26455 is the number of rows meaning trials
118 is the number of channels.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the filter coefficients from a filter design tool (as per linked answer), or using `ellip`. For example, the coefficients of a 6<sup>th</sup>-order elliptic filter with 0.5dB ripples in the 8-35Hz passband and 40dB stopband attenuation operating at 100Hz are given by:

```
Rp    = 0.5;  % 0.5dB ripples in the passband
Rs    = 40;   % 40dB attenuation in the stopband
fs    = 100;  % 100Hz sampling rate
fmax  = fs/2; % Nyquist frequency
[b,a] = ellip(6, Rp, Rs, [8/fmax, 35/fmax]);
```

Then, from [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html#f83-1015962):

> If X is a matrix, filter operates on the columns of X.

So, given an input `X` represented as a matrix where the columns are to be filtered independently (independent channels), you can use:

```
y = filter(b,a,X);
```

to obtain the filtered signal `y` represented as a matrix (same size as `X`). In other words `y(:,i)` will be the filtered output corresponding to the input sequence `x(:,i)`.

Note that `filter` can also operate on the rows of `X`, using the syntax:

```
dim = 2; % the dimension to filter along
y = filter(b,a,X,[],dim);
```